# mapView.delegate = self with current location

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am setting my mapView delegate to self for my pin callout to work and when I do so my current location appears as a pin also. How can i fix that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9j8h.png)

```
    mapView.delegate = self


    self.locationManager.delegate = self


    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest


    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()


    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

Comment: What is your exact question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {     
    if annotation.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation) {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

        if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {

            return nil
        }
```